# Get the current page url in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to retrieve the current page url in a template file, but I can't figure out how to do it in Magento 2.0.

Does anyone know how to get it? (keep in mind I am working in a template / phtml file)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The universal solution: works from anywhere, not only from a template:

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

From a template you can do it simplier: by using the [`\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getUrl()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L745-L748) method:

```
$block->getUrl();
```

An example from the core: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/logout.phtml#L14

Comment: You should be injecting a factory, and not using the objectmanager directly.

Comment: $block->getUrl(); returns the homepage URL, not the current page URL

Comment: @CarComp, I agree with you that the factory should be preferred. But there is nothing wrong with using `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` by itself. It should be used when you need a singleton. However if you need to create multiple new URLs, using `Magento\Framework\UrlFactory` makes more sense.

Comment: Got this search result, in 2021 almost all tutorials/guides advise against using `ObjectManager` directly for any type of implementation.  Answer below that uses `UrlInterface` shows multiple ways to get Urls.

Answer (score 9):

**Don't use object manager instance directly in files**

**With objectManager**

```
$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

**With Factory Method**

```
protected $_urlInterface;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface
    ...
) {
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
}

public function getUrlInterfaceData()
{
    echo $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getUrl();

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getUrl('test/test2');

    echo $this->_urlInterface->getBaseUrl();
}
```

Comment: The factory method above is the best practice way to do it and definitely works. The accepted answer is not the right way to do this. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without **Object Manager**, you can use below line to get **current** `URL` on the **templates** file

```
$this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
```